# How to handle multiple update event when there is more then one replica of a pod

Tags: kubernetes, event-handling, microservices, replicaset, nats-streaming-server

I have two services name Product and  Order.
Order table inside OrderDb has price and productId columns for storing product price and product id that ordered. Order services has 3 replica.

Now, suppose a product is ordered and it's id 80, and a series of sequential update event fired from product service to order services for that particular product:

```
event1:{productId: 80, price: 500}
event2:{productId: 80, price: 600}
event3:{productId: 80, price: 400}
event4:{productId: 80, price: 900}
event5:{productId: 80, price: 100}
```

so the end price should be 100 for that product, but sometimes these events are processed in random order such as

```
event1:{productId: 80, price: 500}
event2:{productId: 80, price: 600}
event5:{productId: 80, price: 100}
event4:{productId: 80, price: 900}
event3:{productId: 80, price: 400}
```

since event 3 processed last, price become 400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally up to your database. I see you put NATS in the tags so I'm assuming you mean you have some kind of worker queue model, but you probably have a database of record behind that with its own consistency model. With event streaming systems where you want to defend against out of order or multi-delivery, you would include more info in the queue message such as an object version, or just the previous price. In the latter, simpler case it would be like

```
event1:{productId: 80, price: 500, oldPrice: 0}
event2:{productId: 80, price: 600, oldPrice: 500}
event3:{productId: 80, price: 400, oldPrice: 600}
event4:{productId: 80, price: 900, oldPrice: 400}
event5:{productId: 80, price: 100, oldPrice: 900}
```

That would let your code refuse to apply the operation if the base state no longer matches. But that's pretty limiting, you don't want everything to fail after a re-order, you just want convergent behavior. This the point where I just yell "VECTOR CLOCKS" and leap out of the window. Designing distributed, convergent systems is indeed quite hard, look up the term CRDT as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue results from not exactly knowing about the delivery guarantees of your message broker (probably NATS).

**First, you should work out which guarantees you need, and then choose a messaging technology**. It makes a huge difference if you need strict ordering on all events, on all events regarding one entity, or no ordering at all. Same goes for delivery semantics: at-most-once, at-least-once, exactly-once.

If those things are clear, then choose messaging technology fulfilling these requirements, **otherwise you will end up adding complexity by workarounds** (like the suggestion by coderanger). There are many messaging protocols out there, like AMQP, MQTT, NATS, Kafka, etc...

Please be aware that this is the cost of having a distributed architecture! There is no way around thinking about the issues of distributed systems when doing microservices.